# Application to show incoming messages on (full-)screen?

Tags: display, raspberry-pi

For a demo setup to be used at a trade show, I am looking for a Raspberry Pi application to display incoming messages in a somewhat attractive way.

Incoming messages arrive on a message-queue over MQTT, I expect to have to do some scripting to receive those messages and somehow forward them to the display application.

The display application should accept new messages (maybe by looking in a directory for files, maybe over a socket, or something else), and show them on the screen, in full-screen mode. It would be nice if this was accompanied by some sort of animation, for instance the old messages scrolling down while the new message appears at the top. Other options, like a continuous scrolling text containing the most recent N messages, would be okay too.

The ability to add some formatting (with rudimentary HTML? Markdown?) would be nice.

Does anyone know about such an application?